# Xamarin Forms: Have I Covered the bases on iOS Push Notifications?

Tags: ios, xamarin.forms, push-notification

### Issue: Different Behavior In 3 Different Contexts

Ok so Ok, in iOS it seems three different things can happen regarding Push Notifications:

1. When a Push Notification is received when the app is ***not*** in the foreground

   - something shows up in Notification Center
   - if the app is opened *by tapping the notification,* either `AppDelegate.DidReceiveRemoteNotification(...)` or `AppDelegate.ReceivedRemoteNotification(...)` is called, apparently depending on which one is implemented (??).
   - if the app is opened *without tapping the notification,* only `AppDelegate.WillEnterForeground(...)`, is called, without any explicit mention of the notification, and *nothing else* happens to acknowledge that a notification was received.
2. When a Push Notification is received when the app ***is*** in the foreground it causes the `UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate`, if there is one, to execute `UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate.WillPresentNotification(...)`.

### Approach: Routing To One Method From All Contexts

So to cover all bases with Push I need to implement something in all three methods: `AppDelegate.DidReceiveRemoteNotification(...) / AppDelegate.ReceivedRemoteNotification(...)`, `AppDelegate.WillEnterForeground(...)`, and `UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate .WillPresentNotification(...)`.

Here are some stubs to show my approach to all this.

First, I created a custom `UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate`, with a `Shared` static member:

```
public class IncomingNotificationHandler : UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate
{
    public static IncomingNotificationHandler Shared = new IncomingNotificationHandler();

    ...
 }
```

Second, inside that class I made a handler that I can route to in every case (again, this is just a stub for debugging purposes):

```
    //sets all parameters to null by default, so it can be called from methods
    //that don't know anything about notifications:

    public void HandleNotificationsIfAny(UIApplication application = null, 
        NSDictionary userInfo = null, 
        Action<UIBackgroundFetchResult> completionHandler = null)
    {
        //checks if userInfo is null, and logs its conclusions about that:

        if (userInfo == null)
        {
            //In the null case, we can get pending notifications from 
            //UNUserNotificationCenter:

            UNNotification[] pendingNotifications = new UNNotification[] { };
            UNUserNotificationCenter.Current.GetDeliveredNotifications(returnedValue => pendingNotifications = returnedValue);

            //Then we log the number of pending notifications:

            Debug.WriteLine("IncomingNotificationHandler: HandleNotificationsIfAny(...): delivered notification count: " + pendingNotifications.Length);

            //And make note of where this was probably called from:

            Debug.WriteLine("IncomingNotificationHandler: HandleNotificationsIfAny(...): may have been called from this.WillPresentNotification(...) OR AppDelegate.WillEnterForeground(...)");
            return;
            });
        }
        else
        {
            //In the non-null case, we log the userInfo

            Debug.WriteLine("IncomingNotificationHandler: HandleNotificationsIfAny(...): just got info: " + userInfo);

            //And make note of where this was probably called from:

            Debug.WriteLine("IncomingNotificationHandler: HandleNotificationsIfAny(...): may have been called from AppDelegate.DidReceiveRemoteNotification(...)");
        }
    }
```

Third, inside the same class, I implemented the single method that's required by `UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate`, and I routed to the handler from it:

```
    public override void WillPresentNotification(UNUserNotificationCenter center, UNNotification notification, Action<UNNotificationPresentationOptions> completionHandler)
    {
        HandleNotificationsIfAny();
    }
```

Fourth, and last, inside `AppDelegate`, I routed to the same handler from both relevant methods:

```
 //I prefer using DidReceiveRemoteNotification because in my experience 
 //the other one is sometimes not reliable:

 public override void DidReceiveRemoteNotification(UIApplication application, 
        NSDictionary userInfo, 
        Action<UIBackgroundFetchResult> completionHandler)
    {              
        //Simply passing on all the parameters called in this method:

         IncomingNotificationHandler.Shared.HandleNotificationsIfAny(application, userInfo, completionHandler);
     }


 //WillEnterForeground also calls the handler without any parameters
 //because it doesn't automatically know anything about notifications:

  public override void WillEnterForeground(UIApplication application)
    {
        IncomingNotificationHandler.Shared.HandleNotificationsIfAny();
    }
```

With that, as it stands, I think I'm handling a notification event in the same way no matter how my app is alerted about it, and even when it's not alerted at all.

Does anyone know if I now have it covered, or if there's some other cases I need to handle?

Answer (score 1):

**For the first scenario: AppDelegate.ReceivedRemoteNotification**

It reflects the objective c method: `application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:`, but this event has been deprecated since iOS 10: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplicationdelegate/1623117-application?language=objc. So I think there's no need to handle this event.

**For the second scenario: AppDelegate.DidReceiveRemoteNotification**

You can still utilize it to handle notifications now if you haven't implemented `UNUserNotificationCenter` and please notice it is only valid after iOS 7+. Moreover, this event will be triggered when app is on the foreground and if your app is on the background, this event only fires when the user clicks the notification to open your application. And there's no way to access the notification's information if the user clicks the icon to open the app.

I don't think handling `AppDelegate.WillEnterForeground` is a good approach, as it will be called each time the app resumes from background to foreground even though there are no notifications.

**For the scenario: UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate**

You could only use this feature after iOS 10. Once you have implemented it on the device iOS 10+, `DidReceiveRemoteNotification` and `ReceivedRemoteNotification` will never be triggered. `WillPresentNotification` will be called when app is on the foreground. `DidReceiveNotificationResponse` will be fired when the app is on the background and user clicks notifications to open it.

As a conclusion, if you want to easily handle the notification `AppDelegate.DidReceiveRemoteNotification` is enough. If you want to consume the new features of `UNUserNotificationCenter`, `AppDelegate.DidReceiveRemoteNotification` and `UNUserNotificationCenter` should be both involved. The prior one for the iOS 7+ devices and the later one for iOS 10+ devices.

**Update:**

For iOS 10+, you could use `UNUserNotificationCenter.Current.GetDeliveredNotifications` to obtain the notifications that are still displayed in Notification Center. And if you only want to support iOS version 10 and later. I think `UNUserNotificationCenter` is enough, there's no need to implement `AppDelegate.DidReceiveRemoteNotification(...)` or `AppDelegate.ReceivedRemoteNotification(...)`.

- If the app is on background / killed state and the user clicks notification to
  open the app, DidReceiveNotificationResponse will be called.
- If the
  user clicks icon to open your app and the app is killed you should
  place your logic code in `FinishedLaunching`.
- If the user clicks icon
  to open your app and app is on background, you can handle
  `WillEnterForeground` as you did before.
- If the app is on foreground,
  handle `WillPresentNotification`.

Comment: You do seem to know your stuff, thanks for chiming in. Your final summary there contradicts my experience. I am implementing the approach I've outlined, and it seems to be working: when the user taps a notification outside the app, the appropriate window opens in the app; when the user sees a notification and goes to the app without tapping the notification, the appropriate window opens in the app; and when the app is open and a notification comes in, the appropriate window opens in the app.

Comment: @LeMotJuiced Ah, it's my fault. I never used this API, but it seems you are right. On iOS 10+ we could use `UNUserNotificationCenter` to obtain the notifications that are still displayed in Notification Center. However, this can only be achieved on iOS 10+. If your application only supports iOS 10+ then `UNUserNotificationCenter` is enough for your requirement. When the app is on background state and the user clicks notification to open the app, `DidReceiveNotificationResponse` will be called.